# fastest interprocess on jailbroken iPhone？

Tags: iphone, macos, ipc, jailbreak

First of all, we are talking about IPC between daemon and apps on Jailbreaked iPhone.

As far as I know, there are 4 ways for communications between processes , They are BSD `socket`, `CPDistributedMessagingCenter, CFMessagePort, CFSocket.`

I want to know which way is the best for very often (like 50 times a second) ,fast, little data (every time 50-1k bytes), reply based communication?

PS:
I saw Distributed Objects on MAC OS X today. I try to run it on iphone but failed.Any one can help? or Distributed Objects doesn't worth to try?

Comment: "The Distributed Objects technology is not available, but you can still use the NSPort family of classes to interact with ports and sockets. You can also use the Core Foundation and CFNetwork frameworks to handle your networking needs." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jailbroken devices, that should not be discussed on SO.

Comment: @RubberDuck I disagree. The question is asking about the fastest method to use when programming IPC on jailbroken devices, which is definitely a programming question.